# What is Kabbalah?

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah

What is Kabbalah in plain and Brief??

Comment: See also http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1028.

Answer (score 8):

The part of the oral Torah comprising the mystical traditions of the Jewish people and religion.

Comment: This Michael Tzadok is a RASHA , SINNER AND MAKES OTHER SIN, HE'S NOT JEWISH, HE'S A MISSIONARY, WATCH A MENUVAL UGH!!!  WATCH THIS VIDEO FROM RABBI TUVIA SINGER - https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=8g71VZrjCpg